# new Date() creating wrong date from typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

All I am doing is creating a new Date object with this code:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

The value I'm getting is:

```
Sat May 11 2019 13:52:10 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
```

Comment: new Date gives you a date according to browser time who in turn asks your OS for the current time. Have you double checked your date & time settings on your computer?

Comment: yes my date and time in the computer is todays date and time. im sorry to not be able to provide mode info but that is all i have unfortunately . edit : its creating the right date in another class , but i do not know why its creating wrong here.

Comment: Are you running this locally or on an online sandbox?

Comment: running locally. edit this is the code :var self = this;
    var curr = new Date();
    var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); and curr is getting this value Sat May 11 2019 14:06:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {} as opposed to todays

Comment: Just tested your code at https://repl.it/@mikaelbrenner/TrustyModestBoards and it's working fine.

Comment: Yeah I tested it as well just in native console and seems to work fine. Is there anywhere else in your app where you work with a date? you could be overriding a default date method accidentally? Especially considering there are places in your app it works fine

Comment: let me see in my application if im doing anything like this. EDIT : i dont think im doing anything like that

Comment: thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

press F12 in your browser. in the console write: new Date(); 
If the date is wrong then its your computer's date which is not set properly. Otherwise like Mikael said, you're running your code on some other machine which has it's date set wrong.

Comment: in my cosole while debugging when i do this :  new Date() im getting it right i m just running on my local machine from where im commenting this im not its possible for me to run elsewhere

Comment: however i do realize when i hover over the file its giving like this as opposed to local : 5000 : webpack:///. not sure why its the first time im noticing this

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all these troubles with timezone, I would recommend to work with UTC instead of your local timezone. UTC is a general time standard and is universal. An ex-colleague of mine showed me this [article](http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-01-12-the-worst-server-setup-you-can-make.html). It might be relevant!

```js
const utcDate = new Date().toUTCString();
console.log(utcDate);
```

My recommendation would therefore be, store your time in UTC, but render it as the local time on your application view.

When you need to convert it back to your local timezone (or your user's local client timezone), this is what you can do:

```js
const utcDate = new Date().toUTCString();
const currentDate = new Date(utcDate).toString();
console.log(currentDate);
```

Comment: i am going to try this in a moment. thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @LuskLuther sure, you're welcome. Hope it works fine!